# Csv download Straming in javascript

Tags: csv, export-to-csv

Hi I want to show the download progress of a large csv file.
Can anyone suggest me some code or logic when the file comes from backend api response

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read through [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). There is a lot of necessary information missing here. Without telling us what language you are working in, the foundation of the code you have laid out so far, etc. it is near impossible to provide an answer to this

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.